# enter value if condition is met in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need help.
I have following problem.
I have a huge excel file with words in A, their syllables in B and
a condition in C. Now I want that if the condition in C is met, as example here "word contains -ess", then i want to mark every syllable of that word in D with e.g. 'discard'. Because one syllable with a certain condition will render the entire word obsolete.

I appreciate your help very much!

`A             B         C      D

hello         he
hello         lo
headless      head              discard
headless      less       ess    discard
worldliness   world             discard
worldliness   li                discard
worldliness   ness       ess    discard`

Answer (score 0):

try this formula in column D

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("ess",A2))),"discard","")
```